# how can i create a jodatime Period with variable PeriodType

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two variables:

```
int duration;
PeriodType periodType;
```

Based on some logic, I find the difference of 2 dateTimes and would only like to store days, minutes OR hours in the final `period`.

How can I create a period object where the type and the corresponding duration is found at runtime ?

```
new Period(0, duration, periodType);
```

returns me a Period with all fields 0

Answer (score 1):

if ***only like to store days, minutes OR hours***

```
PeriodType.days();
PeriodType.minutes();
PeriodType.hours();
```

then

```
final Period per = new Period().withField(periodType.getFieldType(0), duration);
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

here, the method signature you use is

```
Period(long startInstant, long endInstant, PeriodType type)
```

and I suppose `duration` is in millis (a long)

You'll have to use this one

```
Period(long duration, PeriodType type)
```

so try

```
new Period(duration, periodType);
```

it should work

Comment: I tried that originally, but that expects the duration to be in milliseconds. So, if duration is 10 and periodType is Days, it fails again

Comment: Link: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period(long, org.joda.time.PeriodType)

Comment: have you tried `new Period(duration, null, periodType)` as to use the signature `Period(ReadableDuration duration, ReadableInstant endInstant, PeriodType type)`. It forces you to have 'now' as an end instant, but is it a concern for you ?